# What does (x < y) | (x > z) do?

Tags: python

```
def my_function(x,y,z):
    out = True
    if(x < y) | (x > z):
        out = False
    return out
```

Can you help me understand what this is doing? Is it, "out is True, but if x is less than y or greater than z: out is False"? I am unsure about the `|` operator.

Comment: Here's a suggestion: write a unit test that demonstrates the behavior and proves that it matches your expectations.  You'll need three cases: (1) x < y, (2) y < x < z, and (3) x > z.  I would also check the expectations you've built into the input values x, y, and z.  You assume y < z.  What happens if it's not?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it'd be better to write a unit test than this question.

Comment: It's a fair question, given the unusual `|` operator instead of `or`.

Comment: `|` is the "bitwise or" operator, as you would discover if you searched the web for "python operators". In this case the code does the same as `return x >= y and x <= z`, or `return y <= x <= z` for short.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR, someone thought they were clever.

This code takes advantage of some implementation details about booleans and then does some binary integer operations.

To understand it we need to cover a few things:

1. the `>` and `<` operators in a comparison will give back boolean `True` or `False`.
2. Boolean True and False are actually subclasses of int and function as `1` and `0` respectively in operations that expect an integer (try running `True + 1` in your REPL).
3. The `|` operator is [bitwise OR](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) (as opposed to logical OR which is just `or`) which works on integers.

And *now* we can understand the code: the `<>` comparisons gives us a bool that gets used as an integer 1 or 0 and ORed bitwise with the result of the other comparison.

An *even cleverer* person would note that bitwise OR with 1's and 0's would only be 0 if both were 0, and just check for that condition:

```
1 | 1 # 1
1 | 0 # 1
0 | 1 # 1
0 | 0 # 0
```

This code is needlessly obfuscated: there's no reason to treat the True/False as 1/0 just to do bit manipulation when regular boolean logic would work. This will work identically:

```
def my_function(x, y, z):
    return y <= x <= z
```

Comment: Nothing's being "cast" here. Python doesn't cast. `True` and `False` are simply implemented as subclasses of `int` and thus preserve all the behaviours of an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to wrap your head around code you are not sure about is to test it:

```
testValues = [(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
for x, y, z in testValues:
    print("The values are: x = %d, y = %d, z = %d" % (x, y, z))
    print("out is:", my_function(x, y, z))
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def my_function(x,y,z):
    global out
    out = True
    if(x < y) | (x > z):
        out = False
    return out


x = 6
y = 2
z = 5
my_function(x,y,z)
```

The above code outputs True/False based on the values of x,y,z. If x is smaller than y OR if x is greater than z it will change the value of 'out' to False.You can further customize the code to do stuff with the output. Like so:

```
if out == True:
    //some stuff to execute when true
else:
    //some stuff to execute when false
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You have basically just restated the pseudocode they gave.